# Can a boyfriend provide proof of funds for Canadian moving to Australia on a Working Holiday Visa Subclass 417?

Tags: visas, australia, proof-provenance-of-funds, working-holiday

My girlfriend is planning to move to Australia from Canada to live with me (I'm an Australian citizen). She is hoping to start with a Working Holiday visa (subclass 417) for one year, and go from there.

One of the requirements of this visa is "proof of funds". The Candidate must show proof of funds of $5000 AUD to meet this requirement.

https://www.visabureau.com/ says:

> You need to have access to sufficient funds to support yourself at least for the initial stage of your holiday in Australia;

The word "access" in the context seems vague, so...

**My Question:**

Can I provide proof of funds on her behalf as her boyfriend? Or, does she have to provide proof of funds from her own account?

Comment: Guidance on the Australian Department of Home Affairs website https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/work-holiday-417/first-working-holiday-417 says “Provide evidence you have enough money for your stay in Australia. This is usually AUD5,000. You must also show us you have enough money to buy a ticket to leave Australia at the end of your stay, or that you already have the ticket.” I’m no expert but I’d interpret it as meaning the funds must be in the applicant’s name. 3rd party sponsorship isn’t guaranteed eg if the relationship ended during the visa period.

Comment: IMHO working holiday visas are within scope for Travel.SE.  The fact that OP wants to immigrate permanently has no bearing on the question itself.

Comment: I disagree. A one year visit is "living abroad", just like studying for 1 year in a country would be. I think they will get better answers on [expatriates.se].